# Cannot import matplotlib.pyplot because of ArialMT font on Ubuntu

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to update my matplotlib dependency in a docker image Ubuntu 16.04 (`ubuntu:xenial-20200212`) with Python 2.7 (but the same problem occurs using Python 3.7), but when I run `python2.7 -c 'import matplotlib.pyplot'`, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 31, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 36, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1474, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1455, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1095, in __init__
    self.afmlist = createFontList(self.afmfiles, fontext='afm')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 580, in createFontList
    font = afm.AFM(fh)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/afm.py", line 338, in __init__
    parse_afm(fh)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/afm.py", line 326, in parse_afm
    dcmetrics_ascii, dcmetrics_name = _parse_char_metrics(fh)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/afm.py", line 199, in _parse_char_metrics
    vals = dict(s.strip().split(' ', 1) for s in line.split(';') if s)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #3 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Everything worked fine when I used `matplotlib==1.4`, but I'm trying to update to `matplotlib==2.2.5` and then I can't import the `matplotlib.pyplot`.

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul 21 2020, 15:19:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'2.2.5'
```

When trying to investigate a bit further and looking on which AFM font file matplotlib seems to fail, it is when matplotlib is parsing the file `/usr/share/fonts/type1/arial/ArialMT.afm` and more precisely, here are the 5 last lines of the file that `_parse_char_metrics` is handling:

```
C -1 ; WX 333 ; N radicalex ; B -15 599 349 671 ;      
C -1 ; WX 166 ; N fraction ; B -222 -28 392 728 ;      
C -1 ; WX 0 ; N uni206A ; B -114 -134 114 690 ;            
C -1 ; WX 0 ; N uni206B ; B -114 -134 114 690 ;            
C -1 ; WX 0 ; N uni206C; ; B -114 -134 114 690 ;
```

And then it fails. As one can see, the last line contains one more `;` which seems to be the cause of the crash.

Among the font packages that are installed additionally on the machine through `apt-get`:

- `ttf-dejavu-core`
- `libfreetype6-dev`
- `fontconfig`

I'm wondering if anyone has an idea:

1. if this font is a default on Ubuntu, or if I can avoid installing it/remove it
2. if anyone encountered an issue with this font, or not
3. if there is a way to ignore a certain font when loading matplotlib (or if matplotlib should handle this)
4. any other idea? :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My best workaround for now is to manually delete this one font file and then matplotlib works like a charm `rm /usr/share/fonts/type1/arial/ArialMT.afm`